# What do I call this food?

Tags: word-request, image-identification, food

Should I call what is depicted in the image "stir fried mixed vegetables", "stir fried vegetables" or "fried vegetables combination"?

[image: Food]

For stir fry, I'm not sure how to write "stir fry" in past tense and continuous tense.
Can I say these?

> I stir fried vegetables yesterday.
>
> I'm stir frying vegetables.

Comment: It's a *vegetable stir fry* most places I've been, which  is the headline on the page you link. The page also refers to it as a *vegetarian stir fry* (but we omnivores eat it, too, so I don't like that). You can also call it stir fried (or stir-fried) vegetables and everybody will understand you and nobody will think you're weird.

Comment: Sorry, correction: *Vegetable stir fry* is the *title* of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think your suggestion is great(a vegetable stir fry).It's really useful. ^^ By the way, I still wonder those sentenses  " I stir fried vegetables yesterday. and I'm stir frying vegetables." are correct or not.

Comment: They sure are. It's a little easier on readers if you write it *stir-fry*, *stir-fried*, *stir-frying*, but that's getting really picky.

Answer (score 9):

*Stir fry* (or *stir-fry*) can be used as a noun, for dishes which have been prepared with that method, as in

> I cooked vegetable stir-fry yesterday.
>
> I'm cooking up vegetable stir-fry for supper.

*Chinese stir fry* is also commonly heard, as the term originated in a Chinese cookbook; the Western counterpart to *stir-fry* is *sauté*.

To say *vegetable stir-fry* is to describe a particular dish, i.e. a stir-fry that has been prepared entirely with vegetables, as opposed to a *chicken stir-fry* or *pork stir-fry* for example. In contrast, *vegetarian stir-fry* describes a stir-fry which is vegetarian— unless it is made from vegetarians, I suppose.

When cooking for themselves, I don't think most people would refer to any dish as a *combination*, unless citing the title of a particular recipe. That term is associated with discounted options at inexpensive restaurants and fast food joints.

*Stir fry* can also be used as a compound verb, which you can use as you have proposed.

> He stir-fries vegetables and tofu for supper every day.
>
> I'm stir-frying the vegetables so they'll be crispy.

You can also use its past participle (adjectival) form to describe food that has been so prepared.

> She prepared stir-fried vegetables yesterday.
>
> You made stir-fried vegetables again?

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation which helps a lot. Now I'm more understand. It's really useful. ^_^